# How does Monero use DNS to discover seed nodes?

Tags: network, connection, seed-nodes

As far as I'm concerned, there is a hardcoded list of four hostnames
`m_seed_nodes_list = {"seeds.moneroseeds.se", "seeds.moneroseeds.ae.org", "seeds.moneroseeds.ch", "seeds.moneroseeds.li"};`.
Then the system resolves the hostnames to IP addresses using DNS. When I try to `dig seeds.moneroseeds.se`, I don't get an answer. 
So, how does a node resolve them to get know the corresponding IP addresses and hence the seed nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *usually* works, but I broke something when moving the seeder to a new set of servers. It should be working again soon!