# How are Monero seed nodes selected?

Tags: seed-nodes

As far as I understand Monero uses a number of seed nodes to bootstrap new nodes entering the network. And I gather from [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/how-does-monero-use-dns-to-discover-seed-nodes) that the address of those nodes are discovered by resolving some fixed DNS names. However, I was wondering how the actual nodes are chosen? Is it just a list of fixed addresses (and if so, who picked them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS for the seed node lists are managed by the core team. Last I was aware, at minimum, fluffypony has access. The nodes themselves are contributed/managed by various individuals, organizations, developers/core-team members that have nodes with good uptime, bandwidth and fixed IP addresses.